# Expose Foreign key through fluent API

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-fluent-api

Ok, so i have many objects, but lets say for the example that it's just 2 objects, Company, and People, i've cutted out most of the props for easy example:

```
public class Company {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<People> Peoples { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string Bname { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class People {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
    }
```

i prefer not to use data annotation, so i can keep my maps seperated and in on place.
My simplified mapping is:

```
class CompanyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company> {
        public CompanyMap() {

            HasMany(p => p.Peoples)
           .WithRequired();
}}
```

It's seems to work well, people got a fk to company in db, and EF can insert and pull back data, and i can query it if i do it with lambda:

```
var tmp = db.Companies.Include("Peoples")
```

but if i try to query it with linq, and join them up:

```
var tmp2 = from c in db.Companies
           join p in db.Person
             on c.Id equals p.
```

and right there is my problem, People object did not expose it's foreign key from db, so i can't join them up like this.

So my question is, can i expose the fluent api created fk to my object modell, so i can linq it?

Alternatively should i use the lambda one, and map it to my viewmodel somehow, so it wont produce unneeded columns for this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the *FK property* (`CompanyId`) and the *navigation property* (`Company`) to your `People` entity:

```
 public class People {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //...
    public int CompanyId {get;set}
    public virtual Company Company{get;set;}
}
```

Then, move the Fluent Api relationship configuration to the `PeopleMap` class and modify that configuration this way (also map the FK property with the same name that have that FK column in the `People` table):

```
public class PeopleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<People> {
        public CompanyMap() {

            Property(p => p.CompanyId)
                    .HasColumnName("CompanyId");//remember change the name for the real FK column 

            HasRequired(p=>p.Company)
           .WithMany(c=>c.Peoples)
           .HasForeignKey(p=>p.CompanyId);
         }
}
```

After that, you should be able of use `CompanyId` FK property in your query:

```
var tmp2 = from c in db.Companies
           join p in db.Person on c.Id equals p.CompanyId
           //...
```

Comment: I would emphasize that there's no need for joins when these navigation are in place.

Comment: That's true, maybe the OP doesn't know how to work with them yet and due to that it's trying to translate an sql query to a linq query. This [article](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) could help the OP to better understand how to work with navigation properties.

Comment: Yapp i did not know aboit this, pretti new to EF. Thanks for your bonis input guys!